# How to refresh an access token every once in a while

Tags: java, google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I just wrote some code and managed to get my files synchronized with Google Drive. 
But I ask myself a question: how to give to the Drive service a new Access token? Because I don't think that the service will refresh itself automatically! At the beginning I set the GoogleCredentials with an access token, but after that if I want to refresh the access token, I feel like I'm forced to set a new Credential and build a new Drive service. Am I right?

Comment: Welcome to stack we would like to help you but with out knowing what programming language you are using, and seeing your code it will be very hard for anyone to give you an answer to this question.

Comment: Hmmm yes I should have given my programming language. I'm coding in Java. You don't want to see my code, it isn't necessary to answer my question ^^

Comment: please do follow the official google help on this (on drive or on oauth) and let us know the code and what isnt working.